# Javascript Filter Table then select all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, filter, checkbox

I have an html table with a checkbox on each row.  My javascrpt filters rows based on a text box above the table. I need a function that will only check the boxes on visible rows.  I'm stumped.

chkbuild is the name of all the checkboxes in the table.  ID is unique.
chkallnone is my header checkbox to select all or none.

example of table row cell

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="(counter)" name="chkbuild" value="(unique ids)"></td>
```

Javascript code for selecting checkboxes.

```
  function checkCheckboxes( id, pID ){
var ele=document.getElementsByName('chkbuild');  
var TrueFalse = true;
//determine if the select all checkbox is checked or unchecked.
if (document.getElementById('chkallnone').checked) {
    TrueFalse = true;
} else {
    TrueFalse = false;
}
//cycle through all table checkboxes and set their checked value
for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++){  
    ele[i].checked=TrueFalse;  
}
```

}

Comments added 08/23/2022
My table row has `<tr  data-link="filename.php"  data-target="_SELF">` and the javascript has this function which live filters the table.

```
$("table tr").click(function(e) {
var u = $(this).data("link");
var t = $(this).data("target");
console.log(u, t);
if (t.length) {
  window.open(u, t);
} else {
  window.location.href = u;
}
});
```

Comment: How are you managing the state of which rows are being filtered / hidden? Could you apply that same filter logic to the "ele" variable before running the for loop on the contents, so that the changes are only applied to the currently visible items?

Comment: I utilized data-link and  data-target attributes of the tr tag along with javascript to trigger  the refreshing.  I added additional information above.

Answer (score 0):

I have added som emarkup that seems to fit part of your description. The following snippet works in the way that it

- checks/unchecks all the table chekckboxes with `[name=chkbuild]`
- `window.open()`s new windows for all `<tr>`s with the appropriate data tags set.

The target "_SELF" will of course open the new page in the original location, leading to a white page, while all other `data-target` values will not work here in SO because of sandbox restrictions.

```js
// check/unchek all target checkboxes:
document.getElementById("chkallnone").onclick=ev=>
  document.querySelectorAll("table [name=chkbuild]")
          .forEach(c=>c.checked=ev.target.checked);
          
// add click event handler on filtered TRs:
document.querySelector("table").onclick=ev=>{
 const tr=ev.target.closest("tr"); // tr = closest TR parent element
 if (tr.dataset.link>"") {
  console.log(`redirecting to ${tr.dataset.link} in target window ${tr.dataset.target}`)
  window.open(tr.dataset.link,tr.dataset.target);
 }
 
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chkallnone"> all checkboxes</label>
<table>
  <thed>
    <tr>
      <th>this is the first column</th>
      <th>and this is the second one</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-link="filename1.php" data-target="win1">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="filename2.php" data-target="_SELF">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link2 - target self!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="chkbuild" value="1"></td>
        <td>checkbox 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="filename3.php" data-target="win3">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>no data</td>
        <td>and no link</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="chkbuild" value="1"></td>
        <td>checkbox 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="chkbuild" value="3"></td>
        <td>checkbox 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="filename5.php" data-target="win5">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" name="chkbuild" value="4"></td>
        <td>checkbox 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb6" name="other" value="6"> other</td>
        <td>checkbox 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="filename6.php" data-target="_SELF">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link6 - target self!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="filename7.php" data-target="win7">
        <td>data</td>
        <td>link7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb5" name="chkbuild" value="5"></td>
        <td>checkbox 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please note that the "other" checkbox with the text "checkbox 6" behind it is unaffected from clicks on `#chkallnone`. This is by design as its name is not `chkbuild`.